# Cakephp AUTH, different login/logout redirects for prefixes

Tags: cakephp, authentication, routes

Is there way to set different logout routes based on the prefix?

I have Admin, Members as two prefixes, when the session is timed out both of them are redirected to the same login page, I want to set different login pages for each of the prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

Sure is, just check existing url's prefix and update login url accordingly. 
In your `AppController::beforeFilter()` you can do:

```
$loginAction = ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'];
if (!empty($this->request->params['prefix'])) {
    $loginAction[$this->request->params['prefix']] = true;
}
$this->Auth->loginAction = loginAction;
```